# When instantiating generics with `new`, is there any practical difference between including the type parameter or not?

Tags: java, generics, syntax

I'm starting to learn Java, and in my program it appears

```
Stack<Integer> s = new Stack<Integer>();
```

and

```
Stack<Integer> s = new Stack<>();
```

and

```
Stack<Integer> s = new Stack();
```

all compile and produce the output I expect.

Is there any practical difference? Which is preferred?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Stack<Integer> s = new Stack<Integer>();
```

This form was required in Java 5 and Java 6 when generics were first introduced. It is more verbose than necessary since Java 7, however.

```
Stack<Integer> s = new Stack<>();
```

This form was introduced in Java 7 and is equivalent to the above, except the compiler infers the type so that the programmer does not need to repeat it. *This is the preferred form.*

```
Stack<Integer> s = new Stack();
```

This is using **raw types** and is bad. It is allowed for backwards compatibility with versions before Java 5 but the compiler will complain that the assignment of the raw `Stack` to the generically typed `Stack<Integer>` is an "unchecked conversion."

It isn't immediately clear in this example that type safety is being lost, because although the `Stack` created is a raw `Stack<Object>`, no reference to the original, raw `Stack` is held, and `Stack` doesn't allow you to pass a parameter to populate it, but that could happen with another type such as `ArrayList`:

```
List<Integer> numbers = List.of(12, 34, 56);
List<String> names = new ArrayList(numbers); // "unchecked conversion" warning
for (String name : names) {    // ClassCastException
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

Even with `Stack` if we break up the creation and assignment, the problem becomes clear:

```
Stack rawStack = new Stack();           // create Stack of raw types
Stack<String> typedStack = rawStack;    // "unchecked conversion" to
                                        //     strongly-typed Stack
rawStack.push(123);                     // push an Integer
typedStack.pop();                       // ClassCastException
```

In this case, we retained a reference to the original, raw stack, which allowed us to violate type safety. You might say, "Well, I would never do this," but the alternative of creating it strongly typed to begin with, `new Stack<>()`, is just two additional characters.

Comment: That was critical to know that the last version was a raw type. I was about to prefer that way had I not asked. Thank you.

Comment: @DavidI tried  List<String> b = new ArrayList();
        b.add(123); on jdk 1.8 and compilre gave me error integer cannot be casted to String. So we are not loosing the feature of Generics and raw types are not supported.

Comment: @Ravik You're right, but you'll need to add an annotation of `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` to avoid the warning from the compiler.

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect these comments. The problem in this case is the compiler warning, since the full parameterized type is still present on the left-hand side.

Comment: "An earlier version of this answer said that s would lack type safety, but that isn't true since the type is still there in the declaration of the type of s." It's not an issue in this particular case since there are no constructor arguments, but there can be type-safety problems with the raw type version if there are constructor parameters of type `T` (where `T` is the type variable of `Stack`), because then the compiler wouldn't check the type of the argument passed and would allow you to (unsafely) pass any reference type.

Comment: @newacct That's an excellent point. I'll update my answer shortly with an example of that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in all three implementations. For compile time errors compiler will look on the details provided on the left while declaring the variables. 
I have see the difference in the editors Eclipse and IntelliJ where auto complete in eclipse editor it produces `Stack<Integer> s = new Stack<Integer>();` whereas in IJ autocomplete produces `Stack<Integer> s = new Stack<>();`

With `Stack<Integer> s = new Stack();` compiler will give warning unchecked assignment.

Comment: This is not correct. There is no difference between the first two, but the third is using raw types and forfeits type safety.

Comment: @David i just tried this  List<String> b = new ArrayList();
        b.add(123); and compiler gave me error saying integer cannot be cased to String.

Comment: That's true, and I just realized my reasoning is a little off. In this case, because the declaration `List<String>` is in scope the compiler knows it must contain strings, but it gives a warning about an "unchecked conversion" when assigning the raw `ArrayList` to the `List<String>`.

Comment: Yes but the reason that third will use raw types in not correct. Warnings won't stop sucessfull compilation. I have added compiler warning in my answer thanks for pointing that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no practical difference. All are same.
Basically it is just way how we write.

Earlier version of java
     `Stack<Integer> s = new Stack<Integer>();` was mandatory to write but now it's not.

As per me
 `Stack<Integer> s = new Stack<>();` is the best way as you will not get any warning here.